# Extending spring security loadByUsername httpStatusCode

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Hi I'm forcing problem associated with extending functionality of spring security UserDetailsService method. This method is throwing by default UsernameNotFoundException with status code 400(bad request)

```
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: Username): UserDetails {
        if(loginAttemptService.isBlocked(username))
            throw TooManyInvalidLoginRequestException()
        val user = repository.findByEmail(username.toLowerCase())
            ?: repository.findByUsername(username)
            ?: throw AuthenticationUserNotFound()
        return CustomUserDetails(user)
    }

class TooManyInvalidLoginRequestException : ServiceException(TOO_MANY_REQUESTS, EMAIL_BLOCKED_TOO_MANY_INVALID_LOGIN_REQUEST)
```

If I'll try to throw exception defined by myself that is throwing another status code then its overriden for 401 with my message.
Have you any idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global exception controller using Spring's @RestControllerAdvice annotation, something like:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice

data class ErrorResponseDto(erroCode: Int, message: String)

@RestControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionController {
    @ExceptionHandler(TooManyInvalidLoginRequestException.class)
    fun handleCaseOne(e: TooManyInvalidLoginRequestException): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDto> {
        val errorResponseDto = ErrorResponseDto(101, e.getMessage())
        ResponseEntity<>(errorResponseDto, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(SomeOtherException.class)
    fun handleCaseTwo(e: SomeOtherException): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDto> {
        val errorResponseDto = ErrorResponseDto(102, e.getMessage())
        ResponseEntity<>(errorResponseDto, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }
}
```

This might have some Kotlin mistakes, this was ported from a Java code.

Comment: UserDetailsService loadUserByUsername extendet throws UsernameNotFoundException by default